# How do I slicing array in swift? (flatMap)

Tags: swift

I convert 2-dimension array to 1-dimension using flatMap()

and I try to slice array that I flatten.. but I can't it.. How could I slicing array?

```
import Foundation

func solution(_ n:Int, _ left:Int64, _ right:Int64) -> [Int] {
    var array: [[Int]] = []
    
    for i in 1...n {
        var tmp: [Int] = []
        for _ in 0..<i {
            tmp.append(i)
        }
        for j in (i+1)..<(n+1) {
            tmp.append(j)
        }
        array.append(tmp)
    }
    
    var result = array.flatMap { $0 }
    return result[left...right] // no exact mathes in call to subscript
}

print(solution(3, 2, 5))
```

Why Couldn't I slicing that array?

Comment: For a starter: Array indices are `Int` and not `Int64`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the expected result is, but your code has two (type mismatch) issues

1. `left` and `right` must be `Int`, the `Index` type of `Array`

   ```
   func solution(_ n:Int, _ left:Int, _ right:Int) -> [Int] {
   ```
2. To return `[Int]` you have to convert the `Array<Int>.SubSequence` to `[Int]`

   ```
   return Array(result[left...right])
   ```